# ejabberd register from specific ip's

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to setup my ejabberd server to allow user registration from a specific ip adress. So far the only time I can register a user is when I change *ip_access* value to *all*. But thats not what I want.

Here is part of my config file:

```
...
acl:
  ...
  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"
      - "xx.xx.xx.xx"

  register_networks:
    ip:
      - "xx.xx.xx.xx"
...
access:
  ...
  register: 
    all: allow

  trusted_network: 
    loopback: allow

  register_network: 
    register_networks: allow
...
registration_timeout: infinity
...
modules: 
  ...
  mod_register: 
    ip_access: register_network
    access: register
...
```

Neither *trusted_network* or *register_network* work. I always get *403 Forbidden* error. I am using ejabberd 16.01

Answer (score 0):

you have defined `register_networks:` in `acl` but you referred to `register_network` as the `ip_access` value.

It might be the issue there.

Regards,